# Twisted homology of free products

Tags: gr.group-theory, group-cohomology, at.algebraic-topology

Let $G_1$ and $G_2$ be groups and let $M$ be a vector space equipped with actions of $G_1$ and $G_2$.  The free product $G_1 \ast G_2$ thus acts on $M$.  How can one compute the twisted group homology $H_{\ast}(G_1 \ast G_2;M)$ in terms of $H_{\ast}(G_1;M)$ and $H_{\ast}(G_2;M)$?  Since I doubt that $H_{\ast}(G_1;M)$ and $H_{\ast}(G_2;M)$ are enough to completely determine $H_{\ast}(G_1 \ast G_2;M)$, I guess my question more precisely is what additional information is needed?

Comment: @Lewis: You have Meyer-Vietoris sequence, see Ken Brown's book  "Cohomology of groups". Situation is the same as with topological spaces since $H_*(G,M)=H_*(K(G,1), {\mathbb M})$, where ${\mathbb M}$ is an appropriate sheaf on $K(G,1)$. 